# Extract title tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this:

```
date = chunk.find_all('a', title=True, class_='tweet-timestamp js-permalink     js-nav js-tooltip')
```

Which returns this:

```
<a class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" href="/15colleen/status/537395294133313536" title="3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014"><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-long-form="true" data-time="1416959997" data-time-ms="1416959997000">Nov 25</span></a>
```

Obviously `get_text()`returns `Nov 25`, but I want to extract the snippet `3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014`.

Answer (score 8):

You just need `.find` and to extract `["title"]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find("a",attrs={"class":"tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip"})["title"])

3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014
```

Answer (score 5):

Specify the list index along with the title index to get the value of title attribute.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<a class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" href="/15colleen/status/537395294133313536" title="3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014"><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-long-form="true" data-time="1416959997" data-time-ms="1416959997000">Nov 25</span></a>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> date = soup.find_all('a', title=True, class_='tweet-timestamp js-permalink     js-nav js-tooltip')
>>> date
[<a class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" href="/15colleen/status/537395294133313536" title="3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014"><span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp " data-aria-label-part="last" data-long-form="true" data-time="1416959997" data-time-ms="1416959997000">Nov 25</span></a>]
>>> date[0]['title']
'3:59 PM - 25 Nov 2014'
```